# Vue.js: how to list only elements that matches a regexp in my v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'd like to represent two lists of included /excluded products from a content

script is:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            filter_in: "",
            filter_out: "",
            products: {!!  $content->products!!},
            products_free: {!!  $content->available_products()!!}
        }
    });
<script>
```

html is:

```
<div class="row" id="app">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Added products</h3>
                <label for="filter_in">Filter: </label> <input type="text" v-model="filter_in" name="filter_in" />
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <ol>
                    <li v-for="p1 in products">
                        @{{ p1.name }}
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box box-danger">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Available products</h3>
                <label for="filter_out">Filter: </label> <input type="text" v-model="filter_out" name="filter_out" />
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <ol>
                    <li v-for="p2 in products_free" >
                        @{{ p2.name }}
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I v-if someway matching against v-model to display only li elements that have p1.name matching against the string in the input field?

How to do it in vue.js?

something like this .... is it possible?

```
<li v-for="p2 in products_free" v-if="p2 regexp filter_out">
      @{{ p2.name }}
</li>
```

Comment: It would make a lot of sense to filter the data already on the server. Or even change the query you use to get the data. Any reason why you're not doing that?

Comment: well it's a just  list of names... why not eager loading?

Comment: Try using template with v-for and li with v-if https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Template-v-for